# numpy.mean() and pandas.mean() return different values for the mean. Why is this so?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a column in the data frame.

I played with two approaches:
1. converting column to an array and calculating mean using numpy.mean()
2. used pandas.mean() on the column itself
However they return different values.

```
import numpy as np
col1= subdf['V12']
col1=np.array(col1)
col1_mean= col1.mean()
col1_mean
```

This returns: -1.2549951995448174e-15

```
import numpy as np
col1= subdf['V12']
col1_mean= col1.mean()
col1_mean
```

This returns: -1.81065810647492e-15

Why are the two means different?

Comment: Could you provide an example Series which demonstrates this? (Perhaps try from your Series and split it (left and right) and see if still occurs etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mean from pandas and numpy differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042250/mean-from-pandas-and-numpy-differ)

Comment: It is explained in the question marked by @politicalscientist. Clearly from the values, it is a roundup error. Try comparing `subdf['V12'].apply(np.mean)` with `np.array(..).mean()`