# Why conversion ndarray->DataFrame changes values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I have following code, which scales data and then converts it to df. It turns out, that conversion step changes values in array, even both types are the same (float64).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as SKLStandardScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(10)})
scaler = SKLStandardScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(scaled)

print(scaled.mean(), df2.mean().values)
print(scaled.std(), df2.std().values)
print(scaled.dtype, df2[0].dtypes)
```

returns:

```
-6.661338147750939e-17 [-1.11022302e-16]
1.0 [1.05409255]
float64 float64
```

So I calculated mean and std from array and DataFrame. Even both are from the same data, with the same type (no floating-point conversion error) - values are different. Why is it?

Comment: While I can't reproduce the difference in the mean, the difference in `std` is because `numpy` and `pandas` uses different `ddof`. Try `scaled.std(ddof=1)` or `df2.std(ddof=0)`

Comment: thanks, it explains difference in std perfectly :)

Comment: Conversion to dataframe does not actually change anything, as if you run `df2.values` you'll see the same underlying array.  How mean is computed is different though.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042250